# How to post a message to friend's timeline in Unity3d

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game with Unity3d and I have a problem when use FB.Feed()
I read document of facebook and I saw:
"Prompts a user to post a feed story. It can be posted to either his/her own timeline (if toId is blank, or set to the user's own Facebook user ID), or to that of one friend (if toID is set to the user ID of that friend)."

```
public static void Feed(
    string toId = "", 
    string link = "", 
    string linkName = "", 
    string linkCaption = "", 
    string linkDescription = "", 
    string picture = "", 
    string mediaSource = "", 
    string actionName = "", 
    string actionLink = "", 
    string reference = "",
    Dictionary<string,string[]> properties,
    FacebookDelegate callback = null
)
```

and how can I post a message to any my friend's wall with this function?

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to get your friend Id. You can use

```
FB.API ("/me/friends/?fields=id", Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, callback);
 it returns list ID friends.
```

Then, call this to open dialog.

```
FB.Feed(
    toId:"YOUR FRIEND ID",
    link: "https://example.com/myapp/?storyID=thelarch",
    linkName: "The Larch",
    linkCaption: "I thought up a witty tagline about larches",
    linkDescription: "There are a lot of larch trees around here, aren't there?",
    picture: "https://example.com/myapp/assets/1/larch.jpg",
    callback: LogCallback
);
```

that's all.